# Set another button background color in one button onclick() function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change button A background color to color 1 when clicked, and at the same time set button B color to color 2.

Same thing for when clicking button B.

The surprising thing is tow blocks code are totally symmetry, but one block work but another one block does not work.

How could it be?

In my main_js:

```
"function switchVisible_dgc() {

......

var color = '#3e8e41';

$("#dgc_click").css('background-color', color);
color='#325CA8';
$("#agc_click").css('background-color', color);
```

}

```
function switchVisible_agc() {
......

var color = '#3e8e41';

$("#agc_click").css('background-color', color);
color='#325CA8';
$("#dgc_click").css('background-color', color);
```

}

`in my html:`

```
<td width="0">

</td>
<td width="250">
<button class="button button5" 
onclick="switchVisible_agc()"id="agc_click">Agc</button>
</td>
</td>
<td width="250">
<button class="button button5" 
onclick="switchVisible_dgc()"id="dgc_click">Dgc</button>
</td>
</table>`
```

Comment: please add your all code.

Comment: Also, pick native selectors or jQuery selectors.  Switching back and forth is a code smell.

Comment: Also typo.  The selectors use `-` while the ids have `_`.  At least the `getElementById` calls are using a typo

Comment: it is too long for posting here, I have to make a simple version for that, any errors for the above code?

Comment: I do not get it, where is the typo? "document.getElementById('dgc-slider').style.display = 'block';" is not related with this problem , let me delete those words for the  simple

Comment: "do X when Y is clicked" is one of the most commonly asked questions here. Even though X and Y can differ quite a bit, the answer is essentially the same every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be something like this. You might include jQuery if you want.

It would be better to use CSS classes & dynamically assign them instead of modifying style attribute of elements directly.

Variables in this script are global because some outer closure assumed.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(`.button5`);

const switchColors = colors => {

 buttons.forEach( (element, index) => {
  element.style = `background-color: ${colors[index]}`
 });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
 </table>
  <td width="250">
   <button id="agc_click" class="button button5" onclick="switchColors(['red', 'blue'])">Agc</button>
  </td>
  <td width="250">
   <button id="dgc_click" class="button button5" onclick="switchColors(['green', 'yellow'])">Dgc</button>
  </td>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPD:** In case if two pre-determined colors should be switched, the code could also be like:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(`.button5`);

const colors = [`#325CA8`, `#3E8E41`];

const switchColors = () => {

    colors.reverse();

    buttons.forEach( (element, index) => {
        element.style = `background-color: ${colors[index]}`
    });

};
```

Comment: thanks,great, a small question, for this line :"const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(`.button5`);" how program knows the sequence of each button? I mean it could be buttons[0]=agc, buttons[1]=dgc, or  buttons[0]=dgc, buttons[1]=agc,

Comment: @adam You're welcome :)

It scans HTML code from top to bottom in search for specified selector. In this particular case element with `id="agc_click"` is higher, so, it'll always be the first element in `buttons`.

Comment: tks, is there anyway I could extract such as buttons[0].style=...., and buttons[1].style=....? I mean the color is a fixed one, not  the input as the function parameters. I tried something like "buttons[1].style= `background-color: #325CA8`;" but not working, I even put "if (index==0)...." in switchColors(), still not working

Comment: @adam I'll updated my answer because it is a little bit complicated to explain in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by using `addClass()` and `removeClass()`.

```js
$('#agc_click').click(function(){
  $('#agc_click, #dgc_click').removeClass('b2');
  $('#agc_click, #dgc_click').addClass('b1');
});

$('#dgc_click').click(function(){
  $('#dgc_click, #agc_click').removeClass('b2');
  $('#dgc_click, #agc_click').addClass('b2');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.b1 {
    background-color: red !important;
}

.b2 {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="button button5" id="agc_click">Agc</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="button button5" id="dgc_click">Dgc</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```